# Password auth hashing with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, authentication

I have to calculate a password to connect to an api service.
The requirement is:

```
Password = base64 encoded(sha1(nonce+created+secret))
where:
      nonce = 186269
      created = 2015-07-08T11:31:53+01:00
      secret = Ok4IWYLBHbKn8juM1gFPvQxadieZmS2
```

must giving `ZDg3MTZiZTgwYTMwYWY4Nzc4OGFjMmZhYjA5YzM3MTdlYmQ1M2ZkMw==` as password.
I'm approaching with:

```
psw = hashlib.sha1()
psw.update(b"186269")
psw.update(b"2015-07-08T11:31:53+01:00")
psw.update(b"Ok4IWYLBHbKn8juM1gFPvQxadieZmS2")
enc_psw = base64.b64encode(psw.digest())
```

but it give me `2HFr6Aowr4d4isL6sJw3F+vVP9M=` as result

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the length of `'ZDg3MTZiZTgwYTMwYWY4Nzc4OGFjMmZhYjA5YzM3MTdlYmQ1M2ZkMw=='` it is pretty evident that this cannot be the raw message digest. SHA-1 outputs 20 character (160 bit) byte strings.

If we run this through `b64decode()` we get

```
b'd8716be80a30af87788ac2fab09c3717ebd53fd3'
```

This looks fishily like being the hexadecimal representation of the SHA-1 digest instead of the raw bits. It only contains hex digits and the length is exactly 40 characters. With 4 bits per digit, we get exactly the 160 bits from SHA-1.

Let's try:

```
>>> enc_psw = base64.b64encode(psw.hexdigest().encode('ASCII'))
>>> print(enc_psw)
b'ZDg3MTZiZTgwYTMwYWY4Nzc4OGFjMmZhYjA5YzM3MTdlYmQ1M2ZkMw=='
```